# Why is act() required when testing a state update in a custom hook?

Tags: react-hooks, react-testing-library

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-kukjvf?file=src%2Ftest-custom-hook%2FuseCounter.test.tsx) - Open new terminal and `npm t`.

I read the [docs on `act`](https://testing-library.com/docs/preact-testing-library/api/#act) and [this explanation](https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md) and I understood that it just makes sure the states are updated all the way before any assertion. Then they say:

> All renders and events being fired are wrapped in `act`, so you don't really need this.

So if I have a simple `useCounter` hook:

```js
function useCounter(args?: { init: number; by: number }) {
  const init = args?.init || 0;
  const by = args?.by || 1;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(init);

  const increment = () => setCount((p) => p + by);
  const decrement = () => setCount((p) => p - by);

  return { count, increment, decrement };
}
```

and testing it *in isolation*:

```js
test('state update in isolation', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook((props) => useCounter(props), {
    initialProps: { init: 5, by: 3 },
  });
  expect(result.current.count).toBe(5);
  // act(() => result.current.increment()); // use this and test passes
  result.current.decrement(); // use this and test fails: expected 8 and get 5
  expect(result.current.count).toBe(8);
});
```

But my test only passes if I wrap `increment` in `act`. I thought it's supposed to be auto wrapped?

So I'm not sure how I should use `act`, when is it implied and when is it not?

<sub>I'm using both `act` and `renderHook` from `@testing-library/react`, if that makes a difference.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to ensure you are looking at the *correct* documentation. You linked to the Preact-Testing-Library [`act`](https://testing-library.com/docs/preact-testing-library/api/#act) docs.

## Preact-Testing-Library

> ## `act`
>
> Just a convenience export that points to preact/test-utils/act. All
> renders and events being fired are wrapped in `act`, so you don't
> really need this. It's responsible for flushing all effects and
> rerenders after invoking it.

I guess the Preact framework does something "special" with their version of `act` or whatever it is their testing frame is handling it.

## React-Testing-Library

The React-Testing-Library (RTL) docs for [`act`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#act) do not make this same claim that anything is *automagically* wrapped.

> ## `act`
>
> This is a light wrapper around the [`react-dom/test-utils` `act` function](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act). All it does is forward all arguments to the act
> function if your version of react supports act. It is recommended to
> use the import from `@testing-library/react` over
> `react-dom/test-utils` for consistency reasons.

Based on this I'd say that if you are using the RTL [`renderHook`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#renderhook) that the callback that you call in your unit tests should be wrapped in this `act` call.

Comment: Oops I didn't even realize that! I searched for "act" and just clicked the first suggestion. Good catch!

Comment: It still bothers me that it isn't clear when `act` is required, though I guess I should use it whenever `renderHook` is involved, as a rule of thumb.

Comment: @vietan FWIW I generally ignore using `act` until a test fails, in which case React/RTL/Jest typically tell me what is needed. In other words, I think React /RTL is good at informing you when it's missing. Based on the [React act](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act) doc it seems it is needed whenever you are triggering an action/event/etc that will cause the component/hook to re-render/run. For example, think of it in terms of programmatically clicking a UI button `onClick` callback which may trigger some component to rerender and the test should wait for this to finish.

Answer (score 0):

When you're testing a hook like `useCounter`, if you directly change its state like calling `result.current.decrement()`, you need to wrap that action in `act()`. Even though `renderHook()` already handles most things, state updates within the hook need `act()` to ensure your tests behave consistently. So, always use `act()` when directly modifying state in your tests.

You can read this [medium article](https://flyingsquirrel.medium.com/when-should-i-use-act-in-react-testing-library-d7dd22a3340e) for detailed info.